# run a script on remote server

Tags: ssh, sudo

I am trying to run a script on remote server as a root user. I have this line in my shell script.

```
cat /home/myuser/create_user_updated.sh |   ssh myuser@$myip "sudo sh"
```

I get the following error.

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

The script "create_user_updated.sh" works ok if copy the file to remote server and execute it there locally. But it does not work from remote server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can disable tty requirements by sudo:
   run `visudo` and either remove "requiretty" option globally if it is set, or on per-user basis:

   `Defaults:username !requiretty`
2. You can force ssh to allocate pseudo-tty:

   `ssh -t -t myuser@$myip "sudo sh"`

   Note the double -t options, both are needed. Moreover, you need to add `exit` as a last line of your `create_user_updated.sh` script. Otherwise, ssh session might not end properly (because of the forced pseudo-tty creation).

Please use option #2 only if you don't have root rights on the target machine, and cannot change sudo config. #1 is much more clean solution. In my opinion, enforcing tty via sudo does very little from security standpoint.

Comment: After running the script, I get some obscure prompt like sh3.22>> I have to hit ctrl+C to get the normal prompt. How do I avoid this since it must be because of -t -t option.

Comment: I updated my answer with the solution to this. Yes, this is because of -t -t option.

Comment: Don't forget that you can constrain the defaults declaration to not only a single username but to any spec, including command specs.  This allows you to restrict the changes to only specific commands, groups of users or other spec.

Answer (score 0):

Use `visudo` to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file and insert the below line:

```
Defaults:myuser !requiretty
```